# LD_LIBRARY_PATH fails in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ld

I have a bash script that runs this line of code:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib ./xattr infile.txt outfile.txt
```

If I were to call this line directly from the shell, it works fine. However if I run it in the bash script I get this error:

```
update.sh: line 45: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib: No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't LD_LIBRARY_PATH work when it's set in a bash script?

Here's more of the code around line 45:

```
BASE_DIR="/volatile/huanlab/bold/kendal/bioinformatics_database/tmp"
COMP_DIR="$BASE_DIR/compound"

# move to the current directory where xattr.cpp and other files are
cd /users/kharland/software/programs/BioDB-update/dev

# Compile xattr ('make xattr' is the same command I call from the shell
# to compile this program when this program actually works).
make xattr

# loop over each .sdf file in COMP_DIR
for INF in $(ls $COMP_DIR | grep sdf)
do
    babel -isdf $COMP_DIR/$INF -ocan $SMILES_DIR/$INF.csv
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib ./xattr $COMP_DIR/$INF $COMP_DIR/$COMP_FILE
done
```

The contents before these lines are just comments

**edit**

In My makefile, I am compiling with these options

```
LDLIBS=-lm -ldl -lz -lopenbabel
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib:/tools/cluster/system/pkg/openbabel/openbabel-2.3.2/build/lib,-L/tools/cluster/6.2/openbabel/2.3.2/lib
```

and running `ldd xattr` shows that the libraries are indeed linked, so the program executes as expected when invoked from the shell. The only issue is with the bash script. If I remove the LD_LIBRARY_PATH option from the bash script I get an issue where the shared libraries for openbabel aren't found even though ldd shows that xattr knows where the libs are. That's why I have LD_LIBRARY_PATH added in the bash script, I'm attempting to use it as a workaround

**edit**
*(corrected mistake: swapped 'libraries' with 'my code' below)*
*(had wrong file system name below)*

Something just occurred to me. My source code is in the `/users` file system. If my libraries are on a different, mounted file system, would bash have trouble finding these documents?

Comment: Can you share a larger snippet of update.sh  around line 45?

Comment: Are you positive that bash is running the script?

Comment: @Kenster this script is called "update.sh" and I call `bash update.sh` to run it.

Comment: What is the 1st line of the script?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: #!/bin/bash

Comment: OK, just want to make sure you were not passing control somewhere else.

Comment: If you used `-rpath` do you actually need LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: @FatalError no I attempted to explain this (although not very well) in the edit to the post. It works from the shell perfectly fine without LD_LIBRARY_PATH. in the bash script it doesn't work.  Since the error I get when running the script is that the program can't find the libraries I figured maybe setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH would help, but even then it can't find them

Comment: added an edit about the filesystem that the libraries are on, maybe this has something do with the issue?

Comment: Start reducing the problem. Try script with just the identical command that works from command line. If it doesn't work, simplify question. If it does, start adding stuff to script until it breaks.

Comment: The error message indicates the shell is treating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... part as the command to be run, and it's failing to find a file with that name. I asked about the shell because some older shells (like Bourne shell I think) don't support the "FOO=bar some-command" syntax.

Comment: @Kenster you were right on target. I needed to change the line in my bash script to

`\`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/name/\` ./xattr ...`

to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Kenster, the POSIX sh standard requires that syntax -- so while 1970s Bourne doesn't support it, any modern /bin/sh should be fine.

Comment: FYI, `for INF in $(ls $COMP_DIR | grep sdf)` is buggy. You'd be better off with `for inf in "$COMP_DIR"/*sdf*; do ...`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: (Also, best practice is to make only environment variables all-uppercase and capitalized; having all your locals be lowercase means they can't mistakenly conflict with a variable provided by the environment or by built-in shell functionality. Of course, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable, so all-uppercase is correct for it).

Comment: With respect to your edit -- the dynamic linker (not part of bash) looks in locations listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the system's globally-defined library paths. Which partitions LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to shouldn't be relevant -- and Kenster is right that when the bug here is hit, the shell is treating the assignment as part of the command. I'm at a loss as to how or why it's doing that, though; do you have a shebang at the the top of your script? If so, for which shell?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, interesting post. I actually went ahead and made the change to my for-loop in the script. I have `!#/bin/bash` at the top of the script for the bash shell. I'm marking your answer as correct below because I tried it on my own machine and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting environment variables *does* work in bash scripts.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR1=VALUE1 env
```

...run that script, and you'll see output that includes `VAR1` and its value.

Generally speaking, this also works with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d testdir.XXXXXX)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$tempdir env
rm -rf "$tempdir"
```

If you can generate a **minimal** reproducer in which this doesn't occur, that would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Short explanation: In my original script the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instruction was being interpreted as a command instead of an environment variable assignment.

Comment: @kjh, I'm curious as to how and why your original script was generating that behavior; if you figure out how to reproduce it, please do follow up here.